# PHP curl request authentification with GET parameter

Tags: curl

I want to execute a curl request to authentificate user from a distant server

Exemple : 
exec('curl -k -d "j_username='.$name.'&j_password='.$pass.'" URL TO SERVER ', $content);

if the pass entered in the form centaine a special character LIKE this pass : Camilie&

the & in the Get url do a  problem

and if i use urlencode() the server return "connection field" because it can't know password.

Someone know a solution for this problem.

thanks for answer

Comment: Did you URL encode the whole data string or just `$pass`? Using `urlencode()` on just `$pass` should work. Try to replace ampersands in your password with `%26` manually to check if that's really where your problem is.